# How the number of Sun sensors is chosen for a given spacecraft and mission?

Tags: mars, design, mission-design, attitude-determination-and-control, sensors

I have to study an ADCS sensors suite and I am struggling to find a criteria to decide how many and in which directions the sun sensors shall be mounted, considering that they are coupled with star sensors for redundancy, initial acquisition and safe mode. I have read that [Exomars Trace Gas Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_Gas_Orbiter) or TGO had 2 coarse sun sensors, while, for example, [Mars Reconnaissance Orbiter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mars_Reconnaissance_Orbiter) or MRO had 8 sun presence sensors.

What justifies these different architectures?

Comment: Sun sensors and sun *presence* sensors may have slightly different applications and different characteristics.